# Suggested addition to the newsletter, User milestones

Tags: feature-request, feedback, newsletter

Since [feedback is always welcome](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/stack-exchange-site-newsletters/), one thing that could be added to the newsletter is some User milestones. Of course those milestone should be really **Awesome Achievement** and only the X must Awesome should be displayed.

Things like :

- Gold badges
- Reputation milestone  (EX : "UserName is the only the 2nd user to reach 100k reputation)
- Tag Reputation milestone

Comment: `2th`? like `ow my 2th hurts!`?  :-D